# A number minus itself gives infinite

Tags: c++, numbers, infinite

In a special case I have the number 0.068404 in two variables (these change while the program is running so I don't know what is in it).

When I'm substracting by itself, it gives the infinite or precisely a number at the power -9. All booleans operations give me a wrong result.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is just the floating point representation very near zero.  It's not infinite, it's just very small.  That "-9" you refer to is `10^-9` and it's the scientific notation of the number.

Comment: You shouldn't compare floating point numbers for equality. Floating point is [inexact](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith)

Comment: But it should gives 0, it's weird ! When i don't multiply it by a number between 0 and 1 (to change the vector length) it works

Comment: @Render -- It should not "give 0".  Again, floating point is inexact.  See the link I posted.

Comment: It probably should not give 0.  But if you included a minimal complete example I could help illustrate exactly why.

Comment: @paulmckenzie, floating point numbers are not inexact, they are deterministic and well-understood. The challenge is precision when converting from base 2 to base 10 and visa-versa.

Comment: @nicomp When I say inexact, I mean that the representation of a decimal fraction cannot be represented exactly by a binary number, unless the decimal fraction is the sum of inverse powers of 2.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely experiencing floating point rounding issues, a very common problem that has been dealt with time and time again. Consider the following program:

```
float a, b, c;

cin >> a;
b = a;
a = a*3;
a = a/3;
c = a - b;
cout << c << " " << (c == 0) << endl;
```

By all rights you should get a print out of `0 1`, but when you try it [here](http://ideone.com/meiv3i). You get:

```
2.48353e-09 0
```

This is because floating point numbers cannot represent every base 10 number, so rounding errors make straight comparisons a bad idea. You should always use an epsilon, ie:

```
abs(a - b) < eps
```

where `eps` is something like 1e-6.

[Here you can find many more examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: Ok thank you ! First time i'm dealing with this issue in 5 years. Thanks again

Comment: @Render your question will be closed unless you elaborate on this. You should provide a concrete example and then accept this answer.